# rails 4 select distinct on multiple columns in postgres with where and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How do you select multiple fields with distinct values, and other non-distinct fields with them, all in one call with where and limit? I tried .pluck (which supports multiple fields in rails 4), .uniq (which didn't work in my case).

Answer (score 22):

This is what worked for me, when used in the controller action

```
@models = Model.select('DISTINCT ON (field1,field2,field3) *')
     .where(id: params[:id])
     .limit(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit less verbose and more ActiveRecord-centered approach which should work not only for Postgres but for MySQL as well.

```
Model.select('field1,field2').distinct.where(field3: 'value').limit(10)
```